# Not displaying PHP errors

Tags: php, apache, apache2, error-reporting

I've boiled down the problem and made it clean so that it hopefully will be easier for you to help me.

I have a very simple code:

```
<?php
echo "Hello world";
?>
```

This runs perfectly fine.

If I run the following code (parse error) I do not get any errors but the text "Hello world" is still displayed:

```
<?php
echo "Hello world";
piwejfoiwjefoijwef
?>
```

If I place the parse error before the code it does however not display "Hello world":

```
<?php
piwejfoiwjefoijwef
echo "Hello world";
?>
```

When I print phpinfo (in the same file, same directory) I have the following settings:
display_errors  On
display_startup_errors  On
error_reporting 1

If I try to also set the error reporting inside the script and run it with the following code I still do not get any errors or warning but the text "Hello world" is displayed:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE); ini_set('display_errors', '1');
echo "Hello world";
owieufpowiejf
?>
```

My php.ini file has the following values (and I have restarted Apache):

```
error_reporting = E_ERROR & ~E_DEPRECATED
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
```

I am running Apache / PHP / MySQL on the Amazon AMI with on a 64-bit AWS EC2. I am not that knowledgeable with server configurations. The errors started when I transitioned to the Amazon server. Besides error reporting the server and Apache/PHP runs flawlessly.

Please guide me in what I can do to fix the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using E_ALL yet? Also, if you change it in your PHP config file, you might need to restart Apache.

Comment: It's possible that your php is logging to a file, rather than to the page being rendered. Check to see if it's logging to your apache error logs or to it's own custom log (check your php.ini config for `error_log=x`). It might be in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` or `/var/log/php/error.log`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That is a notice.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

reveals it.

### Code I used:

```
<?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');
    echo "Hello world";
    owieufpowiejf

?>
```

### Output:

> Hello world
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant owieufpowiejf - assumed 'owieufpowiejf' in /code/14B4LY on line 5

That's because it's not a parse error, it thinks of it as a constant and tried to parse it as a string. And placing a normal string is a valid statement.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Had to edit php.ini.

Comment: @TomKincaid: It depends, some shared hosts disable `ini_set`.

Answer (score 3):

You can try `error_reporting(-1)`

-1 is the maximum value `error_reporting` can take and always will be.

Comment: Oh my god. That's it. They changed it to a "notice". Probably in some update of PHP. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In your PHP script try setting error_reporting to E_ALL and see if you get a notice..

```
error_reporting(E_ALL)
```

Check out the documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting

Answer (score 2):

Create .htaccess file in your main directory and place:

```
php_flag display_errors on 
# 7 stands for E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE
php_value error_reporting 7
```

Exact values of `error_reporting` constants could be found in the official documentation http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php

Of course you should have mod_rewrite enabled in your server.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and fixed it by editing /etc/php.ini to display_errors = On

Answer (score 1):

Calling `error_reporting()` in the same script that contains the syntax error is never going to work.

```
<?php
echo "Hello world";
piwejfoiwjefoijwef
?>
```

This script in particular does not get you any syntax error, because it does not contain any syntax error. It's just an `echo` statement and a bare constant in the second line. The trailing semicolon can be omitted right before the `?>`

You would get a notice, if it hadn't been turned off. Again, you didn't enable `E_NOTICE` in your other test.

Comment: Adding the `?>` at the end resolved my problem and the errors show up .. Thanks <3